# slowing down a loop in a recursive function

Tags: actionscript-3, recursion

I have a difficult problem with a recursive function. Essentially I need to 'slow down' a for loop within a function that repeatedly calls itself(the function);
Is this possible, or do I need to somehow extract the recursive nature of the function?

```
function callRecursiveFuncAgain(ob:Object):void{
    //do recursive stuff;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        _nextObj=foo
    callRecursiveFuncAgain(_nextObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to slow down the loop? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The idea of slowing down a function sounds more like an awful hack.

Comment: What does the slowing down have to do with the recursion? If you want to slow something down the method is the same whether you're doing something iteratively or recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Try setTimeout

```
function callRecursiveFuncAgain(ob:Object):void{
 // do recursive stuff
 var i = 0;
 function callNext()
 {
   if(i++ < 4)
   {
     _nextObj=foo;
     callRecursiveFuncAgain(_nextObj);
     setTimeout(callNext, 1000);
   }
 }
 callNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some function which will wait for some time or another function which will use much CPU and therefore will slow down your recursive function. Another way would be using debugger and breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Are you serious? If you have a slow computer your CPU will have more load then a fast CPU which will NEVER work in a situation that needs a good solution. It's not even close to a crappy solution.

Try to use the setTimeOut that's in the flash.utils package http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html.

example use: setTimeout(delayedFunction, delay, arguments);
Note that the delay is expressed in milliseconds.

Check the 'clearTimeOut()' function (flash.utils) to clear your setTimeOut when you're done with it.